# When using Selenium, form options that are visibly selected are not submitted (works when tested manually)

Tags: java, selenium

I'm setting up an automated test for a page that has reporting options.  For example, a user can choose what status they want included in the report:

```
<select _ngcontent-c16="" class="multiSelect ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" formcontrolname="formVal" multiple="" name="Status"><!----><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="0: ''">Any Status</option><!----><!----><!----><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="1: 'draft'">Submission in Progress</option><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="2: 'submitted'">Ready for Decision</option><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="3: 'checklist'">Ready for Checklist</option><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="4: 'minorRevisions'">Waiting for Revisions (Minor)</option><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="5: 'majorRevisions'">Waiting for Revisions (Major)</option><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="6: 'accepted'">Ready for Delivery</option><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="7: 'pendingDelivery'">Delivery in Progress</option><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="8: 'delivered'">Delivered to ProQuest</option><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="9: 'withdrawn'">Withdrawn</option><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="10: 'published'">Published by ProQuest</option><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="11: 'rejected'">Rejected</option><option _ngcontent-c16="" value="12: 'committeeReview'">Committee Review</option><!----><!----><!----></select>
```

The test is designed select different options and then check the resulting report to make sure it includes only the specified information.  I'm running into an issue where form options appear to be visibly selected, but they are not actually being submitted.  As you can see below, I've tried this both with Select and locating by css and clicking (Status and Last Event):

```
    commUtil.UnSelectOptionByText(LOC_STATUS_LISTBOX, "Any Status");
    commUtil.UnSelectOptionByText(LOC_LASTEVENT_LISTBOX, "Any Last Event");
    
    /*
    selectOptionByText(LOC_STATUS_LISTBOX, status);
    selectOptionByText(LOC_LASTEVENT_LISTBOX, lastEvent);
    */
            
    getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(LOC_LASTEVENT_LISTBOX + " option[value*='" + lastEvent + "']")).click();
    getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(LOC_STATUS_LISTBOX + " option[value*='" + status + "']")).click();
    
    getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(LOC_FROM_SELECTOR)).sendKeys(from);
    getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(LOC_TO_SELECTOR)).sendKeys(to);
    
    setEmailTo(email);
    
    click(LOC_RUNREPORT_BOTTOM_BTN, null);
```

When the test is running, everything visibly looks correct with either method.  The problem is that whatever option gets selected isn't actually being submitted.

Here is an example of a request when this is done manually:

```
{siteId: 5, submissionStatus: ["withdrawn"], dateFrom: "2018-01-01", dateTo: "2019-09-01",…}
dateFrom: "2018-01-01"
dateTo: "2019-09-01"
deliveryMethod: "email"
emailTo: "validateRunReportAttachment@gmail.com"
reportFields: ["siteSubmId", "submissionStatus", "submitDate", "title", "keyword", "subjectCategory", "tag",…]
siteId: 5
submissionStatus: ["withdrawn"]
```

Here is an example of the same request when done via automation:

```
{siteId: 5, dateFrom: "2018-01-01", dateTo: "2019-09-01",…}
dateFrom: "2018-01-01"
dateTo: "2019-09-01"
deliveryMethod: "email"
emailTo: "validateRunReportAttachment@gmail.com"
reportFields: ["siteSubmId", "submissionStatus", "submitDate", "title", "keyword", "subjectCategory", "tag",…]
siteId: 5
```

Has anyone run across something similar?  Any suggestions in general?  Again, I don't ever have an issue with the reports when run manually.

Comment: could depend on what follows... whether you give the form time to submit before performing another action.  (For instance using the driver to navigate elsewhere would interrupt the previous request sent...)

Comment: The method after this will get the email attachment from Outlook to make sure the report was generated correctly.  

I can verify the issue occurs when I'm debugging and pause directly after clicking to generate the report though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls try to click below 2 elements through Javascript

```
   JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(LOC_LASTEVENT_LISTBOX + " option[value*='" + lastEvent + "']")));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(LOC_STATUS_LISTBOX + " option[value*='" + status + "']")));
```

Comment: When I try that, unfortunately nothing is visibly being clicked/selected.  

I'm not familiar with Javascripst so I entered it exactly as you provided with only this modification to the first line:

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this issue by using actions to move to and then click the element.  I ended up switching from css to xpath for locator, but that was just because finding by text was more useful in making the rest of the test work.  Here is the resulting solution:

```
    commUtil.UnSelectOptionByText(LOC_STATUS_LISTBOX, "Any Status");
    commUtil.UnSelectOptionByText(LOC_LASTEVENT_LISTBOX, "Any Last Event");
            
    WebElement statusOption = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='Status']/*[text() = '" + status + "']"));
    WebElement lastEventOption = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='Last Event']/*[text() = '" + lastEvent + "']"));
    
    Actions statusActions = new Actions(getDriver()); 
    actions.moveToElement(statusOption); 
    sleep(1000);
    actions.click(statusOption); 
    Action statusAction = actions.build(); 
    statusAction.perform(); 

    Actions lastEventActions = new Actions(getDriver());
    actions.moveToElement(lastEventOption); 
    sleep(1000);
    actions.click(lastEventOption); 
    Action lastEventAction = actions.build();
    lastEventAction.perform(); 
    
    
    getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(LOC_FROM_SELECTOR)).sendKeys(from);
    getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(LOC_TO_SELECTOR)).sendKeys(to);
    
    setEmailTo(email);
    
    click(LOC_RUNREPORT_TOP_BTN, null);
```